# Wildfly jsp encoding by jboss-web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, netbeans, encoding, wildfly

I'm working on a corporate project using **Wildfly**. I wonder if there is a way to configure the "**jsp-encoding**" property for a single project and not only in **standalone.xml**, which affects all projects?

I'm using Spring Web MVC 4.0.6 on a Maven project in NetBeans 8.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to add into `web.xml`?:

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```